# django multy level query in foreignkey relationship

Tags: django, django-models

How can I do multy level query? My Model is

```
from django.db import models


class Subjects(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    pub_date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Question(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subjects)
    ques = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ques

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    ans1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ans2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ans3 = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ans1
```

I want to query from Subject No.2 Question no.23 and answer no.2. In reverse order I want to query Answer.objects.get(pk=2) which was the answer of Question.objects.get(pk=23) and that question was from Subjects.objects.get(pk=2).   How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be like this

```
s = Subjects.objects.get(name="No.2")
q = Question.objects.get(subject=s, ques="no.23")
a = Answer.objects.get(question=q, ans2="some answer?")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use relations, or reverse relations if needed:

```
Answer.objects.filter(id=2, question__id=23, question__subject__id=2)
```

That will return you a `Answer` queryset. If you want to have a `Subjects` queryset:

```
Subjects.object.filter(id=1, question__id=23, question__answer__id=2)
```

In the second query, you are using reverse relations, where you use model names in lower case for the relatons. But `Subjects` queryset may have duplicate values because of the one-to-many relation direction. So you can use `distinct()` for removing the duplicates from the result queryset..

[Check documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) for more